# On the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under an entire $f$ satisfying $f(n^{\frac{1}{n}})\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is entire on $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(n^{\frac{1}{n}})\in\mathbb{R}$.  Show then that $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Any suggestions on how to even begin this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar z)} - f(z)$.  Show first that $g$ is entire.  Then show that $g(z) = 0$.  Hint: there is nothing special about $n^{1/n}$ except that it is a real sequence that converges.

Comment: Should you not define $g(z)=f(z)-\overline{f(z)}$ so that $g(z)=2\Im f$?  In this case, $g$ is evidently holomorphic, $g(n^{\frac{1}{n}})=0$ for every $n=1,2,\ldots$ and since $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$, $\{n^{\frac{1}{n}}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a limit point and thus $g\equiv0$ by holomorphic uniqueness.

Comment: $\overline{f(z)}$ is most definitely not holomorphic.  It fails the Cauchy-Riemann equations by minus signs being in the wrong place.  Similarly, $\text{Im}(g)$ also fails Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  Wrote too hastily.  Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith how can we prove that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and we cant have equality?

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas It can't be proved, because it isn't necessarily true.  (For example, $f(z) = z$.)

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith you are right, thank you very much for your quick response!