# If $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$ and $f(n^{\frac{1}{n}})\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I want to show that if $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$ and $f(n^{\frac{1}{n}})\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{R}$.
I think that I should use the identity principle ( or identity theorem ) but I cant figure out how exactly to do it. The set A=$\{n^{\frac{1}{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has an accumulation point which is 1 and is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ and since f is analytic then it is holomorphic on the real axis, so $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ by the identity principle but I think that this explanation is not that good. Any ideas of how to give better proof?

Comment: Take a look at [On the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under an entire $f$ satisfying $f(n^{\frac{1}{n}})\in\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571437/on-the-image-of-mathbbr-under-an-entire-f-satisfying-fn-frac1n) and let me know if it does the job. It also seems that a much, much more general fact is true : if $a_n$ is a convergent sequence and $f(a_n) \in \mathbb R$ for all $n$ for some entire $f$ , then $f(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm curious to see how $f$ would be defined for $x \lt 0$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer yes it is actually what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas Thank you very much for the acknowledgement.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer do you have any idea on how to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and equality cannot exist?